# Why can't I piggy back / Daisy chain surge protectors or a surge protector and an ups?

Tags: power-supply, surge-protection

Assuming I don't exceed the wattage rating of the whole system then why can't a piggy back let say ups to a surge suppressor in order to let say increase the protection of my system.

Let's assume:
I have 1500va APS UPS that has built in surge suppressor and now I want to plug in a Tripp-Lite 6 outlet metal housed surge suppressor to single output of the battery side of the ups.  Everything else is connected to the Tripp lite and nothing else besides the Tripp lite is connected to the ups. 
The total draw is let say 1500watts.

So what is negative about piggy backing surge suppressors?

Can I use the above setup without any detrimental effects.

Comment: Probably because they won't work as you think they will...

Comment: If surge protectors need current limiting. Will that work? Is it redundant?

Comment: Because the fire warden won't let you